# I am trying to take and input from an html form and have it update in the flask database, whats the simplest way to do it?

Tags: python, html, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to take and input from an html form and have it update in the flask database. The age is specific to the user id.

**Here is my html**

```
 <div>
            <form method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">New age</label>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        class="form-control" 
                        id="new_age" 
                        name="new_age" 
                        placeholder="{{user.age}}"
                    >
                </div>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

**Here is my view.route** This is where I know I am messing up. I juts want to take the input from the html form which is **new_age** and replace the existing **age** in the flask database.

```
@views.route('/profile/<int:id>',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def profile(id):
    new_age = User.query.get_or_404(id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_age.age = request.form['new_age']
        try:
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('profile')
        except:
            return "Problem"
    else:
        return render_template("profile.html", new_age=new_age)
```

**Here is my db model**

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    # define all columns stored in table
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    
    age = db.Column(db.String(150))
    dob = db.Column(db.String(150))
    nationality = db.Column(db.String(150))
    address = db.Column(db.String(150))
    postalcode = db.Column(db.String(150))
    postalcode  = db.Column(db.String(150))
    phonenumber = db.Column(db.String(150))
    skills = db.Column(db.String(150))


    # setting a relationship between user and note...
    notes = db.relationship('Note')
```

I don't know what else to try. The forms on database update confuse me.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

try  form need action  to your route

```
<form action='/profile' method="POST">
```